# mongoimport - only one positional argument is allowed for cloud uri

Tags: mongodb

While trying to import a csv file from my local folder into mongoDB cloud, I encounter this problem. MongoDB version is 4.06 and local is MacOS

I am using command line in MacOS as per the script below

```
mongoimport —-uri "mongodb+srv://<userid>:<password>0@cluster0-iszpq.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority" --type csv --headerline  --file demands.csv
```

I expect this to insert the local csv data into the the collection in the MongoDB Cloud. How ever I am getting this error:

error validating settings: only one positional argument is allowed

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your command I would guess the error is due to a problem with your `--uri`. It has a strange character on it:

```
mongoimport —-uri
```

Try changing it to use two hyphens:

```
mongoimport --uri
```

Answer (score 0):

oops I added as extra '-' to the uri flag. My bad